# Logarithm inequality for vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, logarithms

I am trying to prove the following result. Let $d$ be a vector in $\mathbf{R}^{n}$ with $\|d\|_{\infty} < 1$. Then,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \log(1 + d_{i})
\geq \mathbf{1}^{T} d -
\frac{\|d\|_{2}^{2}}{2 (1 - \|d\|_{\infty})},
$$
where $\mathbf{1}$ is the all-ones vector. I think I'm pretty close, but I'm missing a factor of $2$. Here is what I have so far. It is easy to show that
$$
\log(1+z)
\geq \frac{z}{1+z}
= z - \frac{z^{2}}{1+z}
$$
for all $z > -1$: all you do is take the derivative of
$$
f(z) = \log(1+z) - \frac{z}{1+z}
$$
to conclude that the minimum value of $f(z)$ on $(-1,\infty)$ is $f(0) = 0$.

If I apply this result to each term in my sum, I find that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \log(1 + d_{i})
\geq \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( d_{i} - \frac{d_{i}^{2}}{1 + d_{i}} \right)
= \mathbf{1}^{T} d - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{d_{i}^{2}}{1 + d_{i}}.
$$
Then, since $d_{i} \geq -\|d\|_{\infty}$ for all $i = 1 , \ldots , n$, we have that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \log(1 + d_{i})
\geq \mathbf{1}^{T} d - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{d_{i}^{2}}{1 - \|d\|_{\infty}}
= \mathbf{1}^{T} d - \frac{\|d\|_{2}^{2}}{1 - \|d\|_{\infty}}.
$$
But I am missing a factor of $2$! Incidentally, does anyone know if this result has a name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method based on ZachL's comment.

We can write the power series for $\log(1+d_{i})$ as
$$
\begin{align*}
\log(1+d_{i})
&
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} d_{i}^{k}
\\ &
= d_{i} - \frac{1}{2} d_{i}^{2} \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{2 (-1)^{k+1}}{k} d_{i}^{k-2}
\\ &
= d_{i} - \frac{1}{2} d_{i}^{2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{2 (-1)^{k+1}}{k+2} d_{i}^{k}
\\ &
\geq d_{i} - \frac{1}{2} d_{i}^{2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} |d_{i}|^{k}
\\ &
= d_{i} - \frac{d_{i}^{2}}{2 (1 - |d_{i}|)}
\\ &
\geq d_{i} - \frac{d_{i}^{2}}{2 (1 - \|d\|_{\infty})}
\end{align*}
$$
Summing over $i = 1 , \ldots , n$ gives the desired result.

Comment: Nice work... +1

Answer (score 3):

You may begin with $\log(1+x)\ge x - \frac{x^2}{2(1-|x|)}$ instead.

Comment: As for some reason "why" this bound, recall $\log(1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \ldots$ for the region of interest.

Comment: I don't think that this works. I want my inequality to hold for all $d \in \mathbf{R}^{n}$ with $||d||_{\infty} < 1$, but the inequality $\log(1+x) \geq x - \frac{1}{2} x^{2}$ only holds for $x \geq 0$. For example, suppose $n=1$ and $d = -0.9$. Then, we have that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \log(1+d_{i}) = \log(0.1) \approx -2.3 < \mathbf{1}^{T} d - \frac{1}{2} ||d||_{2}^{2} = -0.9 - 0.5 * (-0.9)^{2} \approx -1.3$.

Comment: @Stirling Fixed.

Comment: That works, but I don't think it's that easy to show the starting inequality. However, I was able to do it by differentiating $f(x) = \log(1+x^{2}) - x^{2} + \frac{x^{4}}{2 (1-x^{2})}$ to show that $f(x)$ is increasing on $(0,1)$. The desired inequality follows. ZachL's comment inspired my answer below, which I think is easier.